# Connecting to a server from a client on a different router

Tags: java, sockets, client, serversocket, portforwarding

I am trying to connect to a ServerSocket on one computer at my house from a computer connected to a different router. I have been googling for hours and have already set up port forwarding. I have already tried creating the Socket with my public IP address and the port number, but with no success. My question is: knowing my public IP address, the local IP address of the server, and the port number, how do I create a Socket so that it properly connects to the server?

These are the constructors I have tried, but with no success:

```
new Socket(my_public_ip_address, port);
new Socket(my_local_ip_address, port); <- this one works only if both computers are connected to the same router
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. Can you add the error output/stack trace? 2. Is your client computer within the network shown by your public IP (public router -> client and public router -> second router -> server)? You may not be able to connect to the public interface of the router with the public IP from an internal network. You may try to directly connect to the internal IP of the server or the "public" IP of the second router.

Comment: The issue here is almost certainly that you're using NAT in your router, which breaks the ability to do end-to-end connections. The Java code has nothing to do with it. You need to configure your router to allow the incoming connection; Super User may be a more helpful site for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for your quick replies, I will make sure to try all of your suggestions out tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

First of all: If you are unlucky (like me) you won't be able to build a connection to your server computer. (In my case the university network blocks all incoming connections).

So maybe your Server isn't the problem, but the path (connection) to your Router.

In your case I would first of all try to Traceroute your Server starting at your Client. The Traceroute should at least reach your router. (I am no good with computer networks so pls correct me, if I am mistaken)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that

- pc X has localipX and connected to routerX with publicipX
- pc Y has localipY and connected to routerY with publicipY

You have to do the following:

1. Make a request from X to publicipY over specific port (P)
2. Configure in your routerY to redirect all request from port P will be sent to localipX to portX (the port that X app is listening to).

I'm aware you mentioned you made a port forwarding and so on, but please check the steps above maybe you miss some. If it doesn't work, check your firewall and make sure all used ports are open and investigate all the nodes that connected (i.e X is sending the request, publicipX send the request, publicipY get it and make sure Y gets it).